# Force certain parameters to have positive coefficients in lm()

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, glm, lm

I would like to know how to constrain certain parameters in `lm()` to have positive coefficients. There are a few packages or functions (e.g. `display`) that can make all coefficients, and the intercept, positive.

For instance, in this example, I would like to force only `x1` and `x2` to have positive coefficients.

```
    x1=c(NA,rnorm(99)*10)
    x2=c(NA,NA,rnorm(98)*10)
    x3=rnorm(100)*10
    y=sin(x1)+cos(x2)-x3+rnorm(100)

    lm(y~x1+x2+x3)

    Call:
      lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)       
    Coefficients:
      (Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
    -0.06278      0.02261     -0.02233     -0.99626
```

I have tried function `nnnpls()` in package `nnls`, it can control the coefficient sign easily. Unfortunately I can't use it due to issues with `NA`s in the data as this function doesn't allow `NA`.

I saw function `glmc()` can be used to apply constraints but I couldn't get it working.

Could someone let me know what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

[You can use package penalized](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51194/constrained-least-squares-estimation):

```
set.seed(1)

x1=c(NA,rnorm(99)*10)
x2=c(NA,NA,rnorm(98)*10)
x3=rnorm(100)*10
y=sin(x1)+cos(x2)-x3+rnorm(100)
DF <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)

lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=DF)
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = DF)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
#   -0.02438     -0.01735     -0.02030     -0.98203
```

This gives the same:

```
library(penalized)

mod1 <- penalized(y, ~ x1 + x2 + x3, ~1, 
                  lambda1=0, lambda2=0, positive = FALSE, data=na.omit(DF))
coef(mod1)
#(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3 
#-0.02438357 -0.01734856 -0.02030120 -0.98202831
```

If you constraint the coefficients of `x1` and `x2` to be positive, they become zero (as expected):

```
mod2 <- penalized(y, ~ x1 + x2 + x3, ~1, 
                  lambda1=0, lambda2=0, positive = c(T, T, F), data=na.omit(DF))
coef(mod2)
#(Intercept)          x3 
#-0.03922266 -0.98011223
```

Comment: Thanks, you said "If you constraint the coefficients of x1 and x2 to be positive, they become zero (as expected)", but why is it? Also, in function penalized(), it seems you have to define each parameters to be either positive or negative, can you make them to be free (e.g. lambda3 can be either positive or negative without us specifying it).

Comment: No, `positive = FALSE` means "free". Also, if the actual minimum of the sum of squares occurs for negative estimates, it is quite likely that the minimum in the constrained parameter space occurs for zero.

Comment: This would be more interesting if no package was to be involved; say that one would want to apply it in a non OLS setting.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the package `colf` for this. It currently offers two least squares non linear optimizers, namely `nls` or `nlxb`:

```
library(colf)

colf_nlxb(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = DF, lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0, -Inf))
#nlmrt class object: x 
#residual sumsquares =  169.53  on  98 observations
#    after  3    Jacobian and  3 function evaluations
#                name      coeff SEs tstat pval gradient JSingval
#1 param_X.Intercept. -0.0066952  NA    NA   NA   3.8118 103.3941
#2           param_x1  0.0000000  NA    NA   NA 103.7644  88.7017
#3           param_x2  0.0000000  NA    NA   NA   0.0000   9.8032
#4           param_x3 -0.9487088  NA    NA   NA 330.7776   0.0000

colf_nls(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = DF, lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0, -Inf))
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: y ~ param_X.Intercept. * X.Intercept. + param_x1 * x1 + param_x2 *        
#  x2 + param_x3 * x3
#   data: model_ingredients$model_data
#param_X.Intercept.           param_x1           param_x2           param_x3 
#           -0.0392             0.0000             0.0000            -0.9801 
# residual sum-of-squares: 159
# 
#Algorithm "port", convergence message: both X-convergence and relative convergence (5)
```

You can set the `lower` and/or `upper` bounds to specify the limits as you like for each one of the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

With ConsReg https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConsReg/index.html package you can deal with this kind of problems

You can set bound limits (lower and upper) and also restrictions within coefficients, like beta1 > beta2 which in some cases can be very useful.

Comment: Please [include disclosure in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when posting about your own projects.