# Impose Constraint on Intercept in Linear Regression Using R

Tags: r, constraints, regression, r-caret

I have a linear regression of the form

Y = a + b1 * X1 + b2 * X2 + b3 * X4

I would like to constrain the intercept parameter a to be a => 0
(i.e., a should be a non-negative value).

What are possible ways to do this in R? Specifically, I would be interested in solutions using the caret package.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Sorry. There seems to be a misunderstanding here. I would like to constrain the intercept to be equal or larger than zero. Not imposing it to be exactly zero. In other words, I am looking for a non-negative intercept.

Comment: the `colf` package cited in the duplicate question works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear model.

```
m0 <- lm(wt ~ qsec + hp + disp, data = mtcars)
m0
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = wt ~ qsec + hp + disp, data = mtcars)
#
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         qsec           hp         disp  
#   -2.450047     0.201713     0.003466     0.006755
```

Force the intercept to be zero.

```
m1 <- lm(wt ~ qsec + hp + disp - 1, data = mtcars)
m1
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = wt ~ qsec + hp + disp - 1, data = mtcars)
#
# Coefficients:
#      qsec         hp       disp  
# 0.0842281  0.0002622  0.0072967
```

You can use `nls` to apply limits to the paramaters (in this case the *lower* limit).

```
m1n <- nls(wt ~ a + b1 * qsec + b2 * hp + b3 * disp, 
    data = mtcars, 
    start = list(a = 1, b1 = 1, b2 = 1, b3 = 1), 
    lower = c(0, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf), algorithm = "port")
m1n
# Nonlinear regression model
#   model: wt ~ a + b1 * qsec + b2 * hp + b3 * disp
#    data: mtcars
#         a        b1        b2        b3 
# 0.0000000 0.0842281 0.0002622 0.0072967 
#  residual sum-of-squares: 4.926
#
# Algorithm "port", convergence message: relative convergence (4)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244898/force-certain-parameters-to-have-positive-coefficients-in-lm) for other example solutions.

Comment: Thanks! But how does this constrain the intercept to be non-negative? I.e. zero or any positive number?

Comment: @quantmarketing `lower` is the lower bound of the parameter; in this formulation the intercept parameter x4